# Regex to match pattern between beginning of string and end of line

Tags: php, regex

I am hoping someone can provide a regex to match all between the first occurrence of = at the beginning of a string and last occurrence of = at the end of the first line which has a new line character (\n used to visualise the new line character).

```
==== Section Header ====\n
Section text goes here\n
Another line\n
Yet another line\n
One more line for good measure\n
```

The regex would also match 'Shorter Section Header' in this example:

```
== Shorter Section Header ==\n
Text about some article\n
...\n
```

Same with 'Another Section Header' but not 'A Sub-section' in this example:

```
=== Another Section Header ===\n
Some text\n
More text\n
== A sub-section ==\n
```

Presumably this is a task for \A and \z and/or ^ and $ but I am having no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^=+(([^=])*)=+(?=\\n)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dH2bJ1/2

http://regex101.com/r/dH2bJ1/3

http://regex101.com/r/dH2bJ1/4

Comment: Works a treat in all 3 test cases. Nice work. Thank you!